# Salire/scendere... con quali preposizioni?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

1. Scendo dalle scale.
2. Scendo per le scale.
3. Salgo dalle scale.
4. Salgo per le scale.

A mio modo di vedere sono tutte intercambiabili, anche se la "3" mi suona poco fluida.
Ovviamente ci tengo a precisare che la mia domanda è rivolta alla forma intransitiva.

Ps: il dizionario mi da "per le scale" anche senza "giù".

Comment: La mia impressione è che possano avere un senso leggermente diverso.

Comment: Non sono italiana, quindi posso essere completamente sbagliata, ma "dalle" mi fa pensare che si stia specificando il luogo di provenienza, mentre "per le" mi sembra usato per indicare il posto per cui si sta passando.

Comment: Aneddoto: in un negozio davanti a cui passo ogni tanto c'è un ingresso in discesa che è costituito da una rampa liscia (per carrelli etc.) e da una rampa di scale. Per un po' c'era un cartello che diceva (vado a memoria) “Si prega la clientela di scendere dalle scale”. Poi è stato sostituito con “...usando le scale”. Il problema, ritengo, è che “scendere dalle scale” è ambiguo: può sembrare che si chieda di allontanarsi dalle scale.

Comment: @DaG: Se ho capito bene, il secondo senso che hai indicato sarebbe più o meno simile a quando si dice "scendere dal treno" o, per esempio, "scendi dalla sedia" a un ragazzo che ci si è arrampicato.

Comment: Esattamente, @Charo, e per come è fatto quell'ingresso, è materialmente possibile, scendendo un gradino, passare dalla scala all'adiacente rampa.

Comment: @DaG: Penso questo sia un buon spunto per scrivere una risposta.

Comment: @DaG: grazie mille. Un'ultima precisazione per quanto riguarda "scendere/salire": si può dire "per le scale"  senza l'aggiunta dell'avverbio "giù/su"?

Comment: @Nakamura: Non capisco la ragione di quest'ultima domanda: se l'hai trovato su un dizionario, perché non si dovrebbe poter usare?

Comment: @Charo: ah, scusa non avevo specificato che il dizionario dava soltanto "salire su per le scale", quindi niente con "scendere". Chiedo perché la lingua italiana ha regole ed eccezioni grammaticali ben precise :D e non vorrei sbagliarmi.

Answer (score -1):

**scendere**
*/scén·de·re/*

**intransitivo**
"*Muoversi da un luogo situato più in alto verso uno posto più in basso, andare giù*":

> **+ da**, **per**, **a**, **in**, **verso**:
>   - scendere **dalla** montagna;
>   - scendere **per** le scale;
>   - scendere **al** piano di sotto;
>   - scendere **in** cantina;
>   - scendere **verso** il piano.

**transitivo**
"*Percorrere una via andando dall'alto verso il basso*":
- scendere le scale;
- tirare giù (anche **+ da** ):"*scendere la bottiglia dallo scaffale*"

**salire**
*/sa·lì·re/*

**intransitivo**
 "Muoversi verso l'alto percorrendo un pendio, una salita, dei gradini, ecc.":

> **+ per**, **a**, **su**, **in**:
>   - salire **per** l’erta;
>   - salire **per** le scale;
>   - salire **al** piano di sopra;
>   - salire **in** mansarda;
>   - salire **su** una montagna;
>   **+ con**:
>   - salire **con** l’ascensore;
>   - salire **con** la scala mobile;
>   - siamo saliti in cima **con** la seggiovia;

anche, di mezzi di cui ci si serve per lo spostamento:
”l'ascensore sta salendo"

**transitivo**
*"Percorrere una via, un passaggio, ecc., in senso ascendente"*:
- salire le scale"
Riferito a un luogo che si erge verso l'alto, scalare:
- salire un monte;
- salire il patibolo (subire l'esecuzione della pena capitale).

---

[Fonte](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/salire%20treccani.it/vocabolario/scendere): treccani.it/vocabolario/salire treccani.it/vocabolario/scendere

Comment: Questa spiegazione è tratta da qualche fonte? Se è così, potresti indicarla nel tuo post, per favore?

Comment: @Charo, le informazioni che ho fornito possono essere tratte da qualunque dizionario della lingua italiana. Mando il link alle voci sul dizionario Treccani: 
http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/salire/
http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scendere/

Comment: La persona che ha espresso un voto negativo può spiegare il proprio voto?